# Analyse data discrepancies: Efficiency of wire vs current

Tags: current, resistance, wire, efficiency

Please help me explain why the efficiency of the wire does not follow a distinct path (ie R^2 value is low).

Graph 1 Efficiency of wire vs current:
http://postimg.org/image/p49bzm4ab/

Is is to do with non-linear relationship between resistance and efficiency (see link below)?

Graph 2: Change in temperature vs wire efficiency

http://postimg.org/image/t3oihsb6p/

Comment: Please explain "efficiency of the wire".

Comment: The power in/ the power out *100%

Comment: Given that definition, I'd like to have some of the wire you tested.  It is showing 180% efficiency - free power.  I would say you've got some kind of error in your measuring or in your math.

Comment: How are you measuring power in and power out? Can you draw a schematic, or post a photo of the schematic?

Comment: I am measuring the power left after passing through the wire. The maximum efficiency is not 180% but the axes do extend to past 100% as it has two y axis. 

Here is a table of data found :
http://postimg.org/image/70do12cst/